# Dynamic amount of children, parent orchestrating with useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref

I have a hook (useBout) that generates a single bout. This is re-usable and outputs an array of items, otherwise it outputs convenience functions to trigger simulate/generate/reset of those items.

I have a show component that has another hook (useShow) which will just store id, an array of useBouts outputs.

From the parent level I would like to define the bouts array and be able to track which ones are complete so I can introduce a bout by bout system. So when one of the child components triggers a generate or simulate I'd like the top level show to be updated.

Source code: https://github.com/azz0r/fedsimulator/blob/master/src/pages/season/show/index.js

Simplified example:

```js
    //show container
    export default function ShowContainer(id) {
      const [ boutAmount, setBoutAmount, ] = useState(randomIntFromInterval(boutMin, boutMax))
      const game = useSelector(getGame)
      const show = useShow()

      useEffect(() => {
        const existingShow = game?.shows.find(item => item.id === id)

        if (existingShow) {
          show.load(existingShow)
        } else {
          // no bouts exist, create empty array of the amount we need
          const bouts = new Array(boutAmount).fill({ id: getId(), })

          show.update({
            id,
            bouts,
          })
        }
      }, [ show.id, ])

      return <Show {...show} />
    }
```

```js
    // show
    export default function Show({ bouts, }) {
      const boutsRef = useRef({})
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {bouts.map((item, index) =>
              <BoutContainer
                key={item.id}
                ref={boutsRef}
                order={index + 1}
                model={bouts[index]}
             />)}
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
```

```js
    // bout
    export default function BoutContainer({ ref, model, order, }) {
      const bout = useBout()

      useEffect(() => {
        if (model) {
          bout.load(model)
        } else {
          bout.generate()
        }

         ref = bout
      }, [ brandId, model, ])

      const onReset = () => bout.reset()
      const onSimulate = () => bout.simulate()
      const onGenerate = () => bout.generate()

      return <BoutUI {...bout} onReset={onReset} onSimulate={onSimulate} onGenerate={onGenerate} />
}
```

So my question is; can I track a dynamic amount of refs and sync back a child all the way up to the parent?

Comment: Why do you need to pass refs?

Comment: The bouts aren't connected to a store, only shows are. So I can't dynamically generate useBout instances - can you? I haven't actually tried doing that to a hook

Comment: I see your point actually! I've now passed an onChange function down.